# Receiving data from multiple devices using parallel wired RS232

Tags: serial-port

I'm currently developing a small application for monitoring the power / current our solar collector is generating.

The array is connected to 3 inverters. Every inverter has a RS232 interface, transmitting one Line of information(its current status) every 10 seconds.

Since I want to do the monitoring using a device only having one serial port, I need to come up with a way to be able to read the data from all of the inverters in parallel.
I don't need to send anything to one of the inverters!

Is it possible to just connect 3 RS232 wires in parallel to one serial port? Collisions will be pretty unlikely since every inverter is transmitting only 64Byte / 10seconds ending with a newline, so I could check for variable line lengths to detect collisions.

Comment: EIA/RS-232 is a point-to-point comm link.  Use EIA/RS-485 for multi-drop connections.  Besides the improper electrical connections, feeding three outputs into one input would make determination of the sender impossible, unless that info was embedded in the data.

Comment: what kind of device on the reading side are you using?  why can't you use a USB->serial hub that uses a single USB port to connect to 4 serial ports?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you **should NOT** connect 3 serial output port in parallel. If you do that you are probably going to broke the RS232 output circuitry of your inverters.

You have 3 RS232 outputs, so you need 3 RS232 input, then you can manage these 3 input the way you like: maybe you can buffer the data from each input, and reoutput the data on a single RS232 output, to be connected to your monitoring device.... but you should add some code in the data flow to differentiate the data coming from the 3 inverters.

Maybe you can use some kind of IC that do the job for you, I'm not sure, but maybe that some IC that multiplex multiple RS232 input on a single RS232 output already exist.
Try this search: [rs232 port input multiplexer on Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&q=rs232+port+input+multiplexer&oq=rs232+port+input+multiplexer&gs_l=serp.3...8458.8827.0.8940.4.4.0.0.0.1.143.340.3j1.4.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.Anu6I-WWLus)

Or, if the monitoring device is a Window computer, you can use 3 serial-to-usb converter: that will create 3 virtual COM port on your computer and you can read data from them with any software.

**Update**
About the hypothesis of securing the output circuitry using diods to block reentering current, I don't think it's going to work...
Many year have passed by since last time I've used an RS232 link at low level (so maybe I'm wrong) but I think that there is some kind of handshake going on between RS232 input and output port (speed to use, parity, stop bit...).
Each RS232 port have inputs and outputs signal, both for data and for transmission control, so your multiple RS232 outputs does have some input signals,  and your single RS232 input does have some outputs.
 This mean that your input monitoring RS323 port is going to try to make a handshake with 3 RS323 ports at the same time... and the 3 RS232 ports are probably going to respond at the same time... so I think it's not going to work.

Other than that if you place diodes on your output, you are going to loose 0.7v, I don't remember the tolerance on signal level of RS232, but maybe that 0.7v can be relevant.

Comment: ok, the buffering solution sounds good, but what about securing the output circuitry of the inverters by using diods to block th current from running into the devices?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm not using any handshaking mechanism. I am using the UART pins on the raspberry pi, only connecting GND,VCC,TX,RX to this logic level converter http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/HQ-RS232-3-3V-logic-converter-MAX3232-/270772788718#ht_2326wt_1115 so the flow control pins are not being used. Anyway - If I'd put the diodes on the TX's of the inverters and just test whether it works as expected, would I be off risk of breaking them? And how did you come up with 0.7V?  Thank you!

Comment: 0.7V is the voltage drop of a diode, which should not affect the EIA/RS-232 signal unless it is on the low side, e.g. close to +/-4V.  The real concern should be possible damage to the receiver on the RaspberryPi.  Bottom line is you should simply abandon any idea of connecting more than one Tx line to a Rx input.  It (wired-ORing) is not a valid EIA/RS-232 connection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sort of chuckling at doomsday and wacky answers that so often pop up on stackoverflow...

But anyway, in years gone buy I have used paralleled RS-232 transmit lines using diodes and it can work fine for situations where collisions are unlikely. In one particular application I used this technique there were two input terminals where a user could key in simple commands to control the system (a specialized security system) and it was very unlikely that two people would be trying to control it at the same time from the two different terminals. Amazingly enough there are no problems with voltage levels with most RS-232A receivers I tested at the time and they tolerated the signal characteristics (no negative voltage) that result from the simple use of the diodes in series with the TXD signals. However, if I had to do this again I would likely add a simple pull-down resister and capacitor to ground with a diode between RXD and the cap in a sort of charge pump configuration or a pull-down to negative going handshake signal to ensure the "OR'd" input signal goes truly negative since the RS-232 spec defines +3 to -3v as invalid.

In any case, I would recommend not using this technique except in very specific, limited, and non-mission critical cases and would not use it in the case where you have multiple devices sending information at a programmed interval as in the case of the OP or where there is a software handshake.

In can be a simple solution to the problem of not enough serial input ports but only in a very limited set of environments.