# Multiplex/demultiplex data from one serial port into "virtual" ports

Tags: python-2.7

I am currently working on the design of a measurement system. It has a three instruments mounted on a pan/tilt head, but only one serial line from the instruments to the Beaglebone Black (BBB) that controls everything. Instrument A and B are similar (use the same commands and module). I'm using Python to control everything. During testing, I had additional cables so that I could wire each instrument to a separate port on the BBB, but that is not possible in the final setup.
Since I needed some processing capabilities on top of the pan/tilt head anyway, I'm using a PIC24 device to connect all instrument serial connections to.
My idea is to multiplex the 3 serial connections, for instance by adding a prefix A_/B_/C_ to the commands/replies.
This I can do.

Communications and processing for instrument A and B is done by the same Python module, which has a function measure() that takes the serial port (ie. /dev/ttyO4) as one of the parameters. I'll obviously need to adapt this.

I need to find a way to allow different modules to access three "virtual" ports, with the choice of either stream A/B/C.
So in short: I (think I) need some kind of class/... that opens the serial port and multiplexes/demultiplexes three streams. Instrument A and B are not to be used simultaneously, but A/C and B/C can be used at the same time. Timing is not critical, a couple of hundreds of milliseconds delay is not an issue.

[image: Schematic]

One option would be to use a second PIC to do the reverse of the microcontroller near the instruments, but I suppose this should be possible in Python as well...

Answer (score 1):

I think the elegant solution is to add some code for your PIC to work as a Modbus slave.

There seem to be good efforts already done, so maybe you can use something like [this](https://github.com/worrajak/PICmodbus) as a starting point.

You can have the three UARTs connected to the sensors continuously writing to several Modbus registers and query those from your BBB with something like [pymodbus](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus) or [pylibmodbus](https://github.com/stephane/pylibmodbus).

It will also be possible to use other buses/protocols like CAN, but if you run Modbus directly on the TTL UART (instead of over RS485, which you won't need unless you have long distance or a noisy environment) you don't need any additional hardware. You will have to modify the firmware on your PIC and write some more lines of Python on your BBB.

But if you want to learn something new (assuming you don't know already), Modbus is quite an easy and useful protocol to add to your toolbox. It's still very popular and open (the spec is publicly available and you have tons of info and code).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I'm keeping my first answer as a reference for others, but the question did not refer to sharing the same physical cable for multiple ports so what I wrote here is not really useful somebody misunderstands it the same way I did.

This question has come up a number of times, see for instance [Receiving data from multiple devices using parallel wired RS232](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856645/receiving-data-from-multiple-devices-using-parallel-wired-rs232)

Serial lines are not intended to be multiplexed, if you decide to follow this route I think you'll get many headaches.

Is there a reason not to use a multipoint protocol like RS485, SPI...? I'm sure you'll be able to find [one](https://www.embedded.com/design/connectivity/4023975/Serial-Protocols-Compared) that works for your needs. For RS485, for instance, the 
 investment in new hardware would be [minimal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B667STP) and the software side would be a piece of cake.

Comment: Hi, I do not intend to connect them electrically. The PIC24 at the top takes the RS232 from the three devices and sends them over one serial port. Yes, I could probably convert them all to RS485 (or even RS232 multidrop if I were really up for a challenge-which I'm not), and connect them to one serial port on the BeagleBone. However, that leaves the (sort-of) same question: how do I share access to the same serial port over several modules?

Comment: And why not SPI? Cable length and I don't have three additional lines for chip select...

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. All three devices are connected to your PIC at the same time... so you have a PIC with a total of four serial ports? or you mean that your devices are connected to the PIC by some other means and the PIC relays all data through its serial port?

Comment: Instrument A connected to PIC UART1, B to UART2, C to UART3, and UART4 goes to the BBB. Data coming in from instrument A gets sent to UART4 with prefix A_, instrument B to UART4 with prefix B_ and so on. So the BBB get data on one serial port. received data starting with A_ comes from instrument A, data sent to instrument A should be prefixed by A_. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I've added a small diagram in the question to make things clearer (hopefully).

Comment: Thanks, now it's more clear, I will edit my answer in a while, now that I understood what you want

Comment: Thinking about it what you want to do cries out for Modbus. On BBB's side that would be a piece of cake with pymodbus or minimalmodbus but on the PIC I'm not sure. I think it would be much more elegant than the A-/B-/C- solution but it might not be worth the effort. There must be something better...

Comment: Allright, thanks. I had briefly thought about CAN, but not considered Modbus. I could put a second board with PIC next to the BBB to demultiplex to separate serial ports, but thought it would be a good exercise to do it in code.